# Beginner in regular expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

```
def showRE(a,re)
  if a =~ re
    "#{$`}<<#{$&}>>#{$'}"
  else
    "no match"
  end
end

showRE('He said "Hello"', /(["']).*?\1/)
  #=> "He said <<\"Hello\">>"
```

Can someone please explain why this function returns "Hello". More specifically, the purpose of *?\ and how that results in function returning what it does. I know ["'] finds either '/"' or '/'' and \1 refers to the match of the first group. However shouldn't that return -> 'He said Hello"' since '/'' is the first line of the string that represents what is in the brackets?

Comment: This indentation is really anarchy. Can you clean that up? It helps us understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: A good [regular expression explainer](https://regex101.com) can help illuminate what that regular expression is doing. Barring that, [a good primer book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do) is a good way to go.

Comment: If any of the answers were helpful please consider selecting one.

Answer (score 3):

The regular expression being passed as an argument (which I'll write in "free-spacing" mode, to make it self-documenting), is as follows:

```
r = /
    (      # start capture group 1
    ["']   # match a double or single parenthesis (a "character class")
    )      # end capture group 1
    .*     # match zero or more (`*`) characters (any characters)
    ?      # make the foregoing match (.*) lazy
    \1     # match the contents of capture group 1
    /x     # free-spacing regex definition mode

str = 'He said "Hello"'
  #=> "He said \"Hello\""
str =~ r
  #=> 8 (we have a match beginning at str[8])
```

As `str =~ r` is "truthy", we evaluate

```
"#{$`}<<#{$&}>>#{$'}"
   => "He said <<\"Hello\">>"
```

The key here is that there are *three* global variables in this expression:

```
$` #=> "He said "
$& #=> "\"Hello\""
$' #=> ""
```

The meanings of these variables are given in [this doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/globals_rdoc.html). You will see that:

- $`  contains the string to the left of the last successful match;
- $& contains the string matched by the last successful match; and
- $' contains the string to the right of the last successful match.

So we have (and return)

```
"#{"He said "}<<#{"\"Hello\""}>>#{""}"
  #=> => "He said <<\"Hello\">>"
```

We could alternatively use the class method [Regexp::last_match](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match):

```
last_match = Regexp.last_match
  #=> #<MatchData "\"Hello\"" 1:"\"">
```

`last_match` is an instance of the class [MatchData](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/MatchData.html). That class contains many useful methods, including ones that return the values of the three global variables mentioned above:

```
last_match.pre_match  #=> "He said "
last_match[0]         #=> "\"Hello\""
last_match.post_match #=> ""
```

I cannot say why the match `.*` in the regular expression was made *lazy* (by making it `.*?`).

Comment: Really Impressive